# arvixe hosting - any experiences for hosting MVC application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I am planning to host my ASP.NET MVC 4 application (.NET Framework 4.0) using SQL Server 2008 on Arvixe with their "Personal Classic ASP" plan which costof 5 USD per month.

Their site says it will have unlimited data storage and unlimited data transfer.
I know that all other hosting providers are limiting these both aspects, so I am a little bit concerned here if it is really unlimited, and in that case, if that will give good performance to my users?

Comment: Arvixe Hosting is very very very a horrible and irresponsible company, it;s only money trap. They squeeze money. They are like "Blood sucking parasites"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for a provider to ACTUALLY provide unlimited bandwidth and/or disk space. Here is an ["unlimited" review](http://www.findmyhosting.com/the-truth-about-unlimited-bandwidth/) that may shed some light. When it comes down to it, very very very few sites will actually require enough bandwidth/data transfer for a provider's "unlimited" promise to become an issue.

The goal of "unlimited" is to attract more customers, and hey, it works. No provider wants to be hosting a shady, free porn download or illegal movie download site. They make money per month, and the more effort your site requires, the more of a hassle it is for them.

As suggested in the above link, it is a wise move to first assess how much bandwidth and traffic you think will be needed for your site to function.

For what it counts, it looks like Arvixe has [excellent reviews](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/hosting-reviews/arvixe/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Arvixe Hosting is very very very a horrible and irresponsible company, it;s only money trap. They squeeze money. my advice is change other hosting company.

Comment: You can find more details about "unlimited hosting" over here - https://www.thewebhostingdir.com/web-hosting-guides/top-reasons-to-avoid-unlimited-hosting